# Estimating coefficients of an interaction in a GLMM

Tags: interaction, lme4-nlme

I fitted a Generalized Linear Mixed Model with a Gamma distribution of errors on `lme4`. I included an interaction between two continuous variables (`x:z`). How can I estimate the coefficients (beta, Standard Error) of the first variable (`x`) for different values of the second (`z`)? I would like to report changes in the slope of `x` in a paper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really a general question about linear models. Suppose that your linear predictor is

$$
\eta = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x + \beta_2 y + \beta_3 xz
$$

that is, $\beta_3$ is the interaction parameter.  I *think* what you mean by "the coefficient of $x$ for different values of $z$" is $\beta_1 + \beta_3 z$, i.e. rewriting the expression as 
$$
\beta_0 + (\beta_1 + \beta_3 z) x + \beta_2 z .
$$
In other words, $\beta_1 + \beta_3 z$ gives the expected change in the response (on the linear predictor scale) caused by a 1-unit increase in $x$ at a particular value of $z$.

If you know the variances of $\beta_1$ and $\beta_3$ and their covariance, you can also calculate the variance (and hence standard deviation) of this value. Suppose you have a *contrast vector*: in this case it would be $c=(0~1~0~z)$, since you're interested in the expression 
$$
\beta_1 + \beta_3 z = 0\cdot \beta_0 + 1 \cdot \beta_1 + 0 \cdot \beta_2 + z \cdot \beta_3
$$
then the variance of the expression is $c \mathbf V c^\top$.

Given that you can specify a focal value of `z` you're interested in, in R code, you would use

```
z <- ?? ## a focal value
coefs <- fixef(model)
cc <- coefs["x"] + coefs["x:z"]*z
varcov <- vcov(model)
vv <- varcov[c("x","x:z"),c("x","x:z")]
res_var <- c(1,y) %*% vv %*% c(1,z)  ## variance of the result
res_sd <- sqrt(res_var)
```

Comment: Thanks ! However, I'm trying to do something easier than writing down the formula: I would just write down the betas expressing the relationships between y and x at different levels of z (e.g "while the relationship between y and x is negative at low levels of z (beta=XXXX±XXXX), it gets negative at high levels of z (beta=XXXX±XXXX)". I would like just to estimate those betas and their standard errors. The change is pretty clear from plots, however I would like to add some text.

Comment: I thought that was the question I answered ... just changed y to z to make it match your question better/hopefully make it clearer.

Comment: I'm sorry. I understood later on...

Comment: stack exchange deprecates the use of comments to say "thank you"; if the answer solved your problem, you're encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it ...